# Kronecker product and finite difference discretization for poisson equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finite-differences, poissons-equation, kronecker-product

In [this](https://github.com/mitmath/18303/blob/master/supp_material/poissonFD.ipynb) notebook from MIT's [Intro to Linear PDEs](https://github.com/mitmath/18303/tree/master) course, it is unclear to me why the Kronecker product is used to formulate the coefficients matrix $A$ for solving the linear system of equations $A u = b$. Given Poisson's equation on the unit square with homogeneous boundary conditions (see [Finite Difference Methods for Poisson Equation by Long Chen, UCI Math](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Echenlong/226/FDM.pdf) for general treatment of Neumann and Dirichlet boundary conditions), the goal is to find $u(x,y)$ satisfying

$$
\nabla^2u = f.
$$

The second-order centered difference approximation is represented by a matrix $D \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ for an $n \times n$ equispaced computational grid, but why is the Kronecker product and identity matrix used in $A = I\ \otimes D + D\ \otimes I$ to form the coefficient matrix? Clearly, the ordering of the arguments for the Kronecker product also determines which dimension ($x$ or $y$) the second-order centered difference approximation operates on (from the MIT notes, the matrix form of the equation is $UD + DU = F$ and the matrix $D$ is a linear operator on $U$), but what about for the 3D case?

Here is the Julia code from the notebook that builds the coefficient matrix $A$ for reference:

```
using LinearAlgebra
using SparseArrays

## build n x n 2nd central difference matrix
function cdiff2(n)
    h = 2 / (n+1)
    D = spdiagm(-1 => ones(n-1), 0 => -2*ones(n), 1 => ones(n-1))
    D = D / h^2
end

## build n^2 x n^2 discretization of Laplace operator with zero Dirichlet BCs
function lap(n)

    # sparse second difference matrix and identity
    D = cdiff2(n)
    spI = sparse(I,n,n)

    # Kronecker product
    A = kron(spI,D)+kron(D,spI)
end
```

Edit:

A related question/answer is [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/35165/kronecker-product-representation-of-the-finite-difference-laplacian)

Comment: The 3D case is just $A = D\otimes I\otimes I + I\otimes D\otimes I + I\otimes I\otimes D$

Comment: @whpowell96 This is useful, but would you please elaborate as to why this is the case. I imagine if you explain for the 2D case, the 3D case would become more clear.